# ggvis layer_model_predictions polynomial fit

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

```
mtcars %>%
  ggvis(x = ~mpg, y = ~hp) %>%
  layer_points() %>%
  layer_model_predictions(model = "lm")
```

gives a linear best fit line through the data.  I am looking into how to make a best fit curve of order 2, 3, 4, etc.  Based on [the documentation for layer_model_predictions](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggvis/versions/0.4.3/topics/layer_model_predictions), it states that model "Must be the name of a function that produces a standard model object with a [predict](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.1/topics/predict) method."  This leads to [predict.poly](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.1/topics/poly).  I know that means that I most likely need `layer_model_predictions(model = "poly")`, but how do you specify the order (degree) of the fit within the `layer_model_predictions` function call?

EDIT:

When the solution from eipi10 is applied to a reactive shiny app the accepted answer is giving some trouble.  Posted as a new question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45068254/user-defined-fit-to-ggvis-plot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply a `formula` to `layer_model_predictions`. For example, a third-order polynomial fit is given below.

```
mtcars %>%
  ggvis(x = ~mpg, y = ~hp) %>%
  layer_points() %>%
  layer_model_predictions(model="lm", formula=hp ~ poly(mpg,3))
```

This is slightly different from the way it works in ggplot2 with `geom_smooth`, where you always supply a formula in `y` and `x` (e.g., `formula = y ~ poly(x,3)`), regardless of the specific column names used for the `y` and `x` aesthetics.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, however, when I adapted it to my shiny app (I know, not in the original post) it was unsuccessful.  I have added some sample code to the original post that replicates the error I am getting, any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Based on the "No data supplied to mark" error, it looks like whatever you're doing with `xvar` and `yvar` is not passing data into `ggvis`. I don't know enough about `shiny` or `ggvis` to diagnose the problem. You might want to ask this as a new question if you can't find an answer in existing questions.