# User defined fit to ggvis plot

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I have an app that I want the user to be able to define the order of fit of 2 variables in a scatterplot that a user also defines.  Right now, my attempt at this is proving unsuccessful with the error `Error in x - xbar : non-numeric argument to binary operator`.  I am at a loss as to how to fix this, and any suggestions on how to get this working are appreciated.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "x", label="Select x-axis Variable:", choices=as.character(names(mtcars)),selected='mpg', multiple = FALSE),
  selectInput(inputId = "y", label="Select y-axis Variable:", choices=as.character(names(mtcars)),selected='hp', multiple = FALSE),
  numericInput(inputId = "order", label = "Select Order of fit line", value = 2, min = 1, max = 6, step = 1),
  ggvisOutput("plot1") 
)

server<-function(input,output,session)
{

  vis <- reactive({

  xvar <- prop("x", as.symbol(input$x))
  yvar <- prop("y", as.symbol(input$y))

  mtcars %>%
    ggvis(x = xvar, y = yvar) %>%
    layer_points() %>%
    layer_model_predictions(model = "lm", formula=yvar ~ poly(xvar,input$order))
  })
    vis %>% bind_shiny("plot1")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The best I could come up with is to paste the formula together and use `as.formula`.  This involves using the chosen variables directly; e.g., `input$x` instead of `xvar`. `formula = as.formula(paste(input$y, "~", "poly(", input$x, ",", input$order, ")") )`

Comment: This worked, if you post it as an answer I will accept it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct the formula via `as.formula` and `paste`, using the `input` values.

```
formula = as.formula(paste(input$y, "~", "poly(", input$x, ",", input$order, ")") )
```